# Prediction from linear regression when R2 is low

Tags: regression, predictive-models, least-squares

I would like to ask you: What is the releationship between low R2 (let's say 0,15) and user's ability to predict outcome values of Y given input values if X.

I've read that the low R2 is not necessarily a problem, if you are trying to estimate the value of coefficient(s), but I am not quite sure about predicting Y values of other observation.

Intuitively, when I see a slope from linear regression which doesn't follow data really well, it does not really make a sense to try predict from the model. Of course it is technically posible, but I don't see the practical meaning of the result. Is it possible to formulate any rule of thumb about this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at the relationship between $R^2$ and mean squared error: $$R^2=1-\dfrac{MSE}{TSS/n}$$

Comment: It can be fine to predict values even with a small $R^2.$  (People have become extremely wealthy in the financial markets using relationships that have much smaller $R^2$ than yours; governments have saved many lives basing decisions on regressions with small $R^2;$ and so on.)  A small $R^2$ implies prediction intervals will be relatively large -- of magnitude similar to (or even exceeding) the standard deviation of the response.

Comment: @whuber How can it exceed the standard deviation of the response unless $R^2<0?$

Comment: @Dave Because it combines estimates of the error variance with the error of the prediction.  With low (but still positive) $R^2,$ predictions made near or beyond the null of the explanatory variables will tend to have prediction intervals *far* greater than the response SD.  There is no limit to how wide the intervals can get.

Comment: I just did a simulation and got it to work out that the prediction interval is about $5000$ times as wide as the standard deviation of the marginal $y$, granted that I looked at a prediction for a new point far away from the original $x$ data (on $[0, 1]$, new point was $-100$).